# complete html tags javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have 3 variables.

```
before = "<p>i am a p</p>some text <a href="">"
middle = "URL</a>another text<div>i am after div";
after = "</div>last text"
```

all i want is to find the missings tags in "middle" (from before or after) and only that.

For exampe my middle result should me:

```
before = "<p>i am a p</p>some text"
middle = " <a href="">URL</a>another text<div>i am after div</div>";
after = "last text"
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape you quote of your  link's like:

```
before = "<p>i am a p</p>some text"
middle = " <a href=\"\">URL</a>another text<div>i am after div</div>";
after = "last text"
```

Comment: Thank you for seeing that, but is not the answer I need.